# I created my own package but couln't use functions from my own package

Tags: android

I created my own package by copying files from different packages, I tried to send message using that package by my program abnormally terminate  and the following errors appear.

```
04-10 04:57:02.910: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:03.014: D/gralloc_goldfish(781): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-10 04:57:03.957: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:04.524: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:05.060: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:05.574: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:07.147: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:07.680: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:08.771: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:09.310: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:09.860: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:10.390: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:10.921: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:11.504: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:12.022: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:12.554: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:13.611: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:14.671: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:15.190: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:15.716: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:16.234: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:17.290: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:17.831: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:18.350: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:18.872: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:19.450: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:19.917: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:20.987: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:22.031: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:23.840: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:25.824: I/Choreographer(781): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 04:57:27.260: W/dalvikvm(781): No implementation found for native Loss/BinderInternal;.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
04-10 04:57:27.270: D/AndroidRuntime(781): Shutting down VM
04-10 04:57:27.270: W/dalvikvm(781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: oss.BinderInternal.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at oss.BinderInternal.getContextObject(Native Method)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at oss.ServiceManager.getIServiceManager(ServiceManager.java:39)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at oss.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at oss.SmsManager.sendRawPdu(SmsManager.java:242)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at oss.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:69)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.sms.projectsms.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 04:57:27.320: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 04:57:32.960: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 781 SIG: 9
04-10 05:23:06.260: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:06.390: D/gralloc_goldfish(928): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-10 05:23:07.340: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:07.850: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:09.440: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:10.560: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:11.097: I/Choreographer(928): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-10 05:23:11.731: W/dalvikvm(928): No implementation found for native Loss/BinderInternal;.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
04-10 05:23:11.731: D/AndroidRuntime(928): Shutting down VM
04-10 05:23:11.741: W/dalvikvm(928): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: oss.BinderInternal.getContextObject:()Landroid/os/IBinder;
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at oss.BinderInternal.getContextObject(Native Method)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at oss.ServiceManager.getIServiceManager(ServiceManager.java:39)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at oss.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at oss.SmsManager.sendRawPdu(SmsManager.java:242)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at oss.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:69)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.sms.projectsms.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 05:23:17.080: I/Process(928): Sending signal. PID: 928 SIG: 9
```

Comment: this post is scary -- *runs away*

Comment: I think you didn't get your `Context` of your class. Can you post your some part of your code where you got error.

Comment: import oss.SmsManager;                  SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phno, null, "hello This is LUNA Project", null, null);  When I import the android.Telephony package the code properly works.

Comment: But `oss.SmsManager` is not a native method so you can't imported it as a `oss.SmsManager` and therefore you got error.

Comment: So what is the solution for this problem, I want to make some changes in SmsManager.java file .

Comment: Have you try to import with `yourPackagename.SmsManager`?

Comment: yes, I tried but even though no error message came but if i try to run the program it stopped with a message "Abnormal termination"

Comment: Have you set your minimum and maximum SDK target in your manifest file??

Comment: Yes. you have to....also your target sdk also.

Comment: I am checking the manifest file,I have set it minimum to 8 and  target sdkversion to 17

Comment: At the top something like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prankpros.hot.shahrukh.khan.wallpapers"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: you have to just use  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />